# How to hide criteria in advanced search

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Out-of-the-box advanced search gives a **loooong** list of fields to search by. That **is** good. However, after a customer's scrolled a few times through *Address X...*, they tend to appreciate a more restricted subset of search criteria.   :)

Usually, I just put most of the fields as not searchable, which does the trick. However, I'm not sure how to affect the second part of the dropdown - the one that contains **related** entities' fields.

How do I do that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CRM 2013 you can do the same thing on entity relationships and set them as being searchable (on by default), or not. This is a change from 2011. I can't recall off the top of my head if this is only available for 1:N relationships or if you can do this for N:N as well.

[edit] This will completely hide the other entity from the list of related entities in the advanced find list, from either side.

Comment: Right... The thing is that I wish a field, e.g. *Pling* on the custom entity *Hazaa* to be searchable on the *Account* but not on the *Contact* in advanced search. Is that possible? Such a change needs to be set from the entity that I perform an advanced search from, not the related entity, right? Or am I misunderstanding the suggestion?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the field as searchable AND/OR the relationship as searchable.

For a field: in the field definition
For a 1:N (or N:1) relationship in the lookup field definition AND in the relationship definition
For a N:N relationship: in the relationship definition (no lookup field, one defined in one place)

Eg. a 1:N relationship between Contact and Account (parent account). 
- You can define the parent account lookup field as searchable (show/hide "parent account" in advanced find of contacts)
- You can define the relationship as searchable (show/hide "child contacts" in advanced find of accounts)

Note that a lot of the system fields and relationships are not editable.

What you want to do is change the relationship definition between Pling and Account (searchable) and Pling-Contact (not searchable).

Comment: Hmm... I can't really find it or maybe I'm misinterpreting your answer... Let's talk specifics... When I perform advanced search on *Account* and scroll down to *Related*, I can see three items for *Lead* (those are *Leads*, *Leads (Customer)* and *Leads (Parent Account for Lead)*). How can I get rid of these?

Comment: These are the following relations: (viewed from Account)
1:N lead_customer_accounts
1:N lead_parent_account
N:N accountleads_association

You can view the lists of relationship via customizations > default solutions > entities > account > 1:N or N:N

If you open a relationship, you will find a field called "searchable". If the value is yes, the relation will be shown in advanced find.

Unfortunately, you cannot modify these relationships because they are created and managed by CRM (system managed). This is an annoying limitation of the CRM system.